# Value of indeterminate form — $a_n \to \infty \wedge b_n \to 0$, $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n\cdot b_n = ?$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

$A_n$ and $B_n$ are sequences and $B_n\to 0$ and $A_n\to\infty$.

$\lim_{n\to\infty}A_nB_n$ should be equal to $0$ OR $+\infty$ OR $-\infty$?

I need to answer *yes/no* about this problem. I know the answer is *0*, but the OR is problematic. My answer is *yes(true)* because the fact that the limit is answering for one of the OR conditions, but I'm very not sure about this. Can you explain me this?

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! Please consider taking the time to read the [faq] to familiarise yourself with some of our common practices. In addition, [this page](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/8348) should give you a start at learning how to typeset mathematics here so that your posts say what you want them to, and also look good. As this question appears to be homework, please consider reading [this page](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1803/8348) for information about asking _effective_ homework-related questions. Cheers!

Comment: Your question is very hard to understand. But consider
$a_n = n, \;b_n=\frac{1}{n}$. Then you have $a_n \rightarrow \infty, \;
b_n \rightarrow 0.$ But $a_n b_n=1$ which does not meat one of your three choices.

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot gammatester! Also got something else where I was completely wrong. Thanks once again!

Answer (score 1):

You can't conclude which the result is, from this informations. It is one of [indeterminate forms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indeterminate_form).

Assume that $A_n =n^2 \wedge B_n = \frac{\pm 1}{n}$, then limit is $\infty$.

$$\begin{split}
\lim_{n\to \infty}A_n &=\lim_{n\to \infty}n^2 = \infty\\
\lim_{n\to \infty}B_n &= \lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{\pm 1}{n^2} = 0\\ 
\lim_{n \to \infty}A_nB_n &= \lim_{n \to \infty}n^2\cdot\frac{\pm1}{n}=\lim_{n \to \infty}\pm n = \pm \infty
\end{split}$$

Let $A_n = n \wedge B_n=\frac{1}{n^2}$, also $A_n \to \infty$ and $B_n \to 0$, but limit is $0$.

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}A_nB_n = \lim_{n \to \infty}n\cdot\frac{1}{n^2}=\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{n} = 0$$

Also it can be number from outside your's values. Let $A_n=3n \wedge B_n = \frac{1}{2n}$ and limit will be other.

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}A_nB_n = \lim_{n \to \infty}3n\cdot\frac{1}{2n}=\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{3}{2} = \frac{3}{2}$$

Of course these are simple examples, but I believe, you can see, where this is going. So the answer is **no**, it can be equal to any value.